# apply bitewise and/or on entire column SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Is there  a way to apply bitwise operations on entire column with `MySQL`?
For example:
We have column called "flags" which contains 8 bit integer,
I want to know which flags are "on" at all rows.
Is there a way to do that?
Thanks.

Comment: Post some sample data with expected result

Answer (score 2):

There are aggregate functions called [`BIT_OR()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_bit-or) and [`BIT_AND()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_bit-and).

To find the bits turned on in every row, use `BIT_AND(flags)`   It generates a result with only the bits set that you need. (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3169d/4/0)

```
 SELECT BIT_AND(flags) AS bits_set_in_every_row
   FROM table
```

and get the result you seek.

Answer (score 0):

Apply an entire column for each flag. 
Otherwise you damage s[argability](https://sqlbits.com/Sessions/Event7/Understanding_SARGability_to_make_your_queries_run_faster) plus the index would be larger.